# adding multiple jars in Oozie-Spark action

Tags: apache-spark, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

I'm using HDP2.6. where is installed oozie 4.2. and Spark2.

After I tracked Hortonworks guide on this site: https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.1/bk_spark-component-guide/content/ch_oozie-spark-action.html for adding libs for Spark2 in 4.2. version of Oozie.

After I submit the job with this add-on:

```
oozie.action.sharelib.for.spark=spark2
```

The error I'm getting is this:

```
   2017-07-19 12:36:53,271  WARN SparkActionExecutor:523 - SERVER[] USER[admin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Workflow2] JOB[0000012-170717153234639-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000012-170717153234639-oozie-oozi-W@spark_1] Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain], main() threw exception, Attempt to add (hdfs://:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20170613110051/oozie/aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.6.jar) multiple times to the distributed cache.
    2017-07-19 12:36:53,275  WARN SparkActionExecutor:523 - SERVER[] USER[admin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Workflow2] JOB[0000012-170717153234639-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000012-170717153234639-oozie-oozi-W@spark_1] Launcher exception: Attempt to add (hdfs://:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20170613110051/oozie/aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.6.jar) multiple times to the distributed cache.
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempt to add (hdfs://:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20170613110051/oozie/aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.6.jar) multiple times to the distributed cache.
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$13$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(Client.scala:629)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$13$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(Client.scala:620)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq.foreach(ArraySeq.scala:74)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$13.apply(Client.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$13.apply(Client.scala:619)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.prepareLocalResources(Client.scala:619)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.createContainerLaunchContext(Client.scala:892)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:171)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1228)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1287)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:745)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.runSpark(SparkMain.java:311)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.run(SparkMain.java:232)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:58)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.main(SparkMain.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:239)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)
```

I have read that new Spark2 will not work with Spark 2.1 (via oozie anyway) due to a change in how Spark handles multiple files found in distributed cache, as mentioned here: [see here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18099)

Keep in mind that I'm using Ambari and HDP2.6. How can I deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the content of the `oozie` directory and `spark2` directory into the Oozie sharelib. If there are any jars present into both, just remove them from one place and try again. Also, do execute the oozie admin sharelub update command to update it.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried with deleting all jars from one of them which exists in both folders `oozie` and `spark2` and didn't work. But one thing I haven't done is to update sharelib after I deleted them and went straight up to test it. I'll try with updating sharelib after what you have purpose and later tell you how that finished :)
Thank you btw :)

Comment: After vacation I finally tried what you said and yes, its working now. Thank oyu very much :)